# Como sair de um método antes de terminar em c#

Tags: c#

O que devo fazer para parar a execução de um metodo antes dele terminar, sair e continuar a execução?

```
public void MEUMETODO()
{

   ...

   PARA E SAIR AQUI();

   ...


}
```

Comment: Se o método retornasse algo como faria?

Comment: Me parece uma pergunta válida, se básica. Porque o voto contra?

Comment: @OnoSendai não tenho a certeza, mas talvez seja por "Esta pergunta não mostra nenhum esforço de pesquisa". Um voto negativo nem sempre é significado da pergunta ser inútil (que neste caso não é) ou que não seja explicita.

Comment: @CêsarMiguel precisamente

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existem duas formas de sair/terminar a função:

- return
- Throw

Podes usar um `return;` em qualquer ocasião para terminar a função:

```
public void MEUMETODO()
{    
   ...

   return;

   ...    
}
```

Ou utilizar o `Throw` quando ocorre uma excepção:

```
public void MEUMETODO()
{    
   try
   {
       ...
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {                    
       throw;
   }
}
```